# Can't seem to get syntax information when in insert mode

Tags: vimscript, syntax-highlighting, indentation, functions

This is for an indent function that should maintain the indentation should the cursor happen to be in a string region. It maintains the indentation when I hit `==` in normal mode but changes when I open a new line in the same string.

```
if synIDattr(synID(line('.'), line('.'), 0), 'name') =~ 'string'
  return -1
else
  return correct_indentation
endif
```

Running the function in insert mode returns an empty string:

```
<C-R>=synIDattr(synID(line('.'), line('.'), 0), 'name')
```

The docs don't mention anything about editing modes, just that it'll give different result when in **gui** mode from when in **term** mode

Comment: *If* I remember correctly, when in insert mode try to use `col('.') - 1` or similar, to check *before* the character you are actually just inserting. Ah, I see that Christian's answer suggests exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

The [function `synID`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#synID%28%29) has to be called with the line and column position of where you want to get the syntax information from. Therefore, you need to replace the second `line('.')` call by a `col('.')` call.

If you get a zero, this means, that there is no syntax information available for that position. This could be the case, because in insert mode, your cursor is usually one column behind the last inserted text.

Comment: i meant to write `col('.')` on the second argument, small mistake. I've just noticed it returns an empty string because the newly opened line has no text. Is there a way around this? i really need it

Comment: why do you need this in a new line?

Comment: For correct indentation when in a multiline string for example. Why does `synID` fail exactly when there's no content on the line? How else would one detect whether they are in a string or code section?

Comment: I think, use col('.') -1 if available. Because in insert mode with col('.') you are outside of any context.